# Apache crash if I try to use ProxyPass on localhost to expose different services as subdomain

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, proxypass

I  have the following directory structure for multiple websites and services

```
/var/www/html/site1
/var/www/html/site2
/var/www/html/site3
/var/www/html/serv1
/var/www/html/serv2
```

`site1` folder hosts a website `site1domain.com` I want to expose the webapp services hosted in `serv1` and `serv2` folders in order to show them as

```
service1.site1domain.com
service2.site1domain.com
```

So I have tried to configured the virtual host in `site1domain.conf` file in this way

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1domain.com
    ServerAlias www.site1domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1
    <Directory /var/www/html/site1>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName service1.site1domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequest Off
    ProxyPass        "/" "localhost/serv1"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "localhost/serv1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName service2.site1domain.com
     ProxyPreserveHost On
     ProxyRequest Off
     ProxyPass        "/" "localhost/serv2"
     ProxyPassReverse "/" "localhost/serv2"
</VirtualHost>
```

But the virtual host code blocks related to services cause a crash of the server: exit with error code 1.

Could someone help me to understand how to configure them properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName service1.site1domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/serv1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName service2.site1domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/serv2
</VirtualHost>
```

No mod_proxy needed.

Comment: Not sure about the crash. Check the error log. For site1domain.com/service, try an [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias).

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused by your [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [`ProxyPassReverse`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) directives not having the *scheme* part of the URL. The correct syntax would be e.g.

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost/serv1" 
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost/serv1"
```

However, Andrew is correct in that *reverse proxy* isn't required nor best technology for this use case.

Comment: It's odd that that would cause the service to crash.

Comment: This is a syntax error in a configuration file, so I find it expected.